# Ruby on rails drop down

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, select, drop-down-menu

I have a simple html select drop down like this

```
<select name="day">
<option value="1" selected="selected">Monday</value>
<option value="2">Tuesday</value>
</select>
```

How do i read the value of the selected option in my controller class in ruby on rails.

Comment: You will have to POST the selection to the corresponding action in your controller.

Comment: Can i do params[:day] in my controller class?

Answer (score 0):

you can access all form fields with `params[:field_identifier]`

Comment: But in the case of drop down would this return the value of selected element?I tried doing it , but it returns empty value

Comment: do you have a form_for arround your select pointing to your resource `<%= form_for @model do |f| %>` ?

Comment: no i thought we can get values of html select using params[:select_id]

Comment: you need a form to send field values via HTTP request, otherwise no params will be send to your controller